# Remotely Check/Start/Stop Services

Tags: c#, service, remoting, restart

I am trying to write a windows form app that will let me check/start/stop services on multiple servers.  I have my code setup to check services on the local machine but I can't figure out how to check the remote machine:

```
    try
        {
            ServiceController machsmint = new ServiceController();
            machsmint.ServiceName = "MACHSMIntegration";

            if (machsmint.Status.ToString().ToLower() == "stopped")
            {
                label_machsmINTSTATUS.Text = "Service is not Running";
            }

            if (machsmint.Status.ToString().ToLower() == "running")
            {
                label_machsmINTSTATUS.Text = "Service is Running";
            }
        }
    catch
        {
            label_machsmINTSTATUS.Text = "Service is not Running";
        }
```

Where do I need to add the code to connect to the remote machine or am I going in the complete wrong direction here?  I'm sorry if this is a stupid question!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServiceController` provides a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssbk2tf3.aspx) that allows specifying the name of the remote machine.

Comment: Okay so I changed my service controller to this:

`ServiceController machsmint = new ServiceController("MACHSMIntegration", "SERVER1");`

This now works on my servers that run windows 2003 but the servers that are running 2008(sp2) are not working.  Is there something different in 2008 that I need to do?

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to a security setting b/c my 2003 servers use NT credentials but my 2008 servers use a local user.  Is there a way to use this with something like an impersonator class to impersonate that local user?