# How to Connect to a Server and Start/Stop Server Remotely?

Tags: c#, service

I am trying to code a program that can start and stop services on my server remotely.

My main concern is how to make the client and server communicate

Can you guys give me some hint on how start about?

I have read about this:
[Remotely Check/Start/Stop Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299134/remotely-check-start-stop-services)

but that dude just connect to the server without any autentication. I tried his method and I encountered authentication issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In command line you can use the following, maybe this is already everything you need:

```
sc \\machine stop/start <service>
```

Comment: Thanks but how about authenticating yourself to the remote server?

Comment: I think the only possibility is a 'workaround', so that the call of sc.exe will be from the given user: 'Runas /user:Domain\user "sc \\machine stop/start service"'